# sql server CASE - getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. 
I have the following query.
What I like to do is if when there is a record that EXIST, I like to assign Actual Date to 'N/A'
else I like to have it be the CreatedBy date that is in Hand.

```
   select ActualDate = (CASE
                         WHEN EXISTS
                         (select NeedHand from Truck 
                           where Truck.NeedHand = 0 and Truck.ID = '34343')
                         THEN
                          'N/A'
                         ELSE
                          SELECT  CreatedByDate from Hand  where ID = '34343'
                         END )
```

I get the following message:
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you need to remove "END CASE" and just have "END".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your query.  The version below should take care of all of them:

```
select  ActualDate = 
CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS(
            select NeedHand from Truck 
            where Truck.NeedHand = 0 and Truck.ID = '34343'
            )
     THEN
               'N/A'
     ELSE
               (SELECT  CreatedByDate from Hand  where ID = '34343')
END
```

I had to :

1. change `EXIST` to `EXISTS`
2. change `END CASE` to `END`
3. add parens around your last query.

Answer (score 3):

Your EXIST should be EXISTS, I think.

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1

```
SELECT
(
    CASE
        WHEN 
                Exists(SELECT top 1 NeedHand FROM Truck 
                WHERE Truck.NeedHand = 0 and Truck.ID = '34343')
        THEN
                'N/A'
        ELSE
                (SELECT TOP 1 CreatedByDate FROM Hand WHERE ID = '34343')
    END 
)
```

### Option #2

```
SELECT
(
    CASE
        WHEN 
                ((SELECT top 1 NeedHand FROM Truck 
                WHERE Truck.NeedHand = 0 and Truck.ID = '34343') IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
                'N/A'
        ELSE
                (SELECT TOP 1 CreatedByDate FROM Hand WHERE ID = '34343')
    END 
)
```

Added `Top 1` to avoid the following issue

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.